# In HTML template, the filter is not working in AngularJS v 1.2.20 (latest version)

Tags: angularjs, filter, ng-options

I'm using angularjs (v1.2.20) in my application.

I'm using the following code snippet to bind the value in a dropdown with the comparator condition. But the dropdown values are getting blank,

```
<select id="countries" class="form-control" ng-model="countries.country" ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries | filter: { "NewYork": countries.cities.name }" required/>
```

Here, the "filter: { "NewYork": countries.cities.name }" condition is not working.

But It was working in the lower version of AngularJS 1.2.7.

Can anybody help me Is this problem with the latest version of AngularJS (v1.2.20)?.
Or
Please let me know If I need to change anything in the code.

Thanks,

Periyasamy

Answer (score 0):

It Needs to be reversed,

It should be

```
<select id="countries" class="form-control" ng-model="countries.country" ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries | filter: { countries.cities.name: "NewYork" }" required/>
```

See a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ntHzmeCRA0XT1ZzrdIl4?p=preview) watch for the filter

```
filter:{phone:'555-1276'}
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/pmOqdlMu9Vg7PbsGmPJG?p=preview) To have nested objects lookup

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Let me try this now and update to you.

Comment: Hi, Yes the filter is working only based on "country" (filter: { countries.name: "US" }"). But its not working based on a "city" (filter: { countries.city.name: "New York" }"). I mean in this case the "filter" is not working when we search by a sub array element. In my case, the "countires" is main array and the "cities" is sub array. Also this issue is happening only in latest version of Angular JS (v1.2.20). Is the latest version has issues? or please let me know how can we fix it?

Comment: @Pramachan: Included an updated fiddle which looks for a nested object hope that helps now

Comment: Hi Thanks for your great help:).

Finally I got the filter is working for nested objects/arrays,

As Per the below link, the filter will not work for the latest versions ( v > 1.2.10). Also the solution is here,

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6222 http://plnkr.co/edit/uB7Mta?p=preview

I just updated my code as below and the filter is working for nested objects,

| filter: { cities: {name: "NewYork" }}

Thanks again for all:)